# How to get the modulus of log(z) $|\int_{|z|=R}\frac{\log(z)}{z^2}dz| \leq 2\pi(\frac{\pi + ln(R)}{R})$

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, complex-integration, arc-length

This is the full question.

Show that $|\int_{|z|=R}\frac{\log(z)}{z^2}dz| \leq 2\pi(\frac{\pi + ln(R)}{R})$ and then use L'Hopital's rule to show that the value of this integral tends to $0$ as $R$ tends to infinity.

This is what I have so far:

$\gamma(t) = Re^{it}$

$\gamma'(t) = Rie^{it}$

$|\gamma'(t)| = R(1)(1)$

$length(\gamma) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|\gamma'(t)||dz| = 2\pi R$

$$|\int_{|z|=R}\frac{\log(z)}{z^2}dz| \leq \int_{|z|=R}|\frac{\log(z)}{z^2}||dz|$$

$$ ................\leq \int_{|z|=R}\frac{|\log(z)|}{|z^2|}|dz| $$
$$.........................\leq \int_{|z|=R}\frac{|\ln|z| + Arg(z)|}{R^2}|dz| $$
$$...................\leq  2\pi R \frac{|ln|z| + Arg(z)|}{R^2} $$
$$.............\leq 2 \pi \frac{\ln(R) + \pi}{R}$$

I am confused about going from $|ln|z| + Arg(z)|$  to $|ln(R) + \pi|$. I assume that since we are dealing with the principle argument, that we are going from $-\pi$ to $\pi$, and since we are going counter clockwise, this just means $\pi$. But, I'm not too sure about the natural log part as well as what happens to modulus symbol (|...|).

I wanted to also see if the following way of thinking was correct. The most that $|z|$ can be is $R$, which means $|z|^2 = R^2$, and so $\frac{1}{|z|^2} = \frac{1}{R^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

$|ln|z| + Arg(z)|\leq |\ln |z||+|Arg(z)|=|\ln R|+|Arg (z)|=\ln R+|Arg (z) | \leq ln(R) + \pi $ assuming that $R>1$ so $\ln R$ is positive.

For the last part of the question we are integrating over $|z|=R$ so $|z|$ is actually fixed. Ne need to maximize it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! How do we know that $R>1$?

Comment: We are interested in limit as $R \to \infty$ so the estimate has been made assuming that $R>1$.  @mathnoob

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense now! I'm not understanding "$|z|$ is actually fixed. No need to maximize it," part, though. I thought that we should use the ML estimate, and I've been taught to see what the maximum would be.

Comment: Sorry, I want to upvote your answer, but I need more "reputation".